# Is it possible to transfer my Azure metrics to Prometheus for monitorin?

Tags: azure, prometheus, microsoft-dynamics, prometheus-alertmanager, dynamics-business-central

My company has already been using Prometheus to monitor AWS and other tools the technology team is using. We introduced Azure too since Microsoft D365 (which they are also using) is now cloud based offering. Azure contains some built-in metrics that we would like to transfer to Prometheus so that Prometheus is the single point of reference. How is that possible ?

Comment: Any update on this one ? did you manage to find out a proper way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

Azure metrics exporter should do the job for you. https://github.com/RobustPerception/azure_metrics_exporter
If you are using Grafana to visualize Prometheus metrics you can connect your Grafana directly to Azure

Comment: No other solution emerged ? I'm thinking of an azure official way of doing ?